# Is it possible to capture screenshot in android and save it to the gallery with unity

Tags: java, c#, unity-game-engine, plugins

I have the free version of Unity, can I capture a screenshot and save it a custom path in internal storage so that it shows in the gallery?

Can it be done with managed plugin for unity?

So far I have tried various plugins but none have worked for me.

```
protected const string MEDIA_STORE_IMAGE_MEDIA = "android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media";
protected static AndroidJavaObject m_Activity;

protected static string SaveImageToGallery(Texture2D a_Texture, string a_Title, string a_Description)
{
    using (AndroidJavaClass mediaClass = new AndroidJavaClass(MEDIA_STORE_IMAGE_MEDIA))
    {
        using (AndroidJavaObject contentResolver = Activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getContentResolver"))
        {
            AndroidJavaObject image = Texture2DToAndroidBitmap(a_Texture);
            return mediaClass.CallStatic<string>("insertImage", contentResolver, image, a_Title, a_Description);
        }
    }
}

protected static AndroidJavaObject Texture2DToAndroidBitmap(Texture2D a_Texture)
{
    byte[] encodedTexture = a_Texture.EncodeToPNG();
    using (AndroidJavaClass bitmapFactory = new AndroidJavaClass("android.graphics.BitmapFactory"))
    {
        return bitmapFactory.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("decodeByteArray", encodedTexture, 0, encodedTexture.Length);
    }
}

protected static AndroidJavaObject Activity
{
    get
    {
        if (m_Activity == null)
        {
            AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
            m_Activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        }
        return m_Activity;
    }
}




public void CaptureScreenshot()
{
    StartCoroutine(CaptureScreenshotCoroutine(Screen.width, Screen.height));
}

private IEnumerator CaptureScreenshotCoroutine(int width, int height)
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(width, height);
    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
    tex.Apply();

    yield return tex;
    string path = SaveImageToGallery(tex, "Name", "Description");
    Debug.Log("Picture has been saved at:\n" + path);
}
```

Comment: I remember your first and now deleted comments + other non deleted ones from the answer in your other question. Just by reading them, I do suggest you learn the [basics of Unity](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials) before asking more questions. You will save yourself and other SO users time. By understanding the basics, you will be able to apply a solution that is given to you to solve your problem. Otherwise, you will be waiting for someone to write a full complete script for you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should works:

```
string ImagePath = "file:///storage/emulated/0/<FileSystemRoot>/";
Texture2D texCopy = new Texture2D(tex.width, tex.height, tex.format, tex.mipmapCount > 1);
File.WriteAllBytes(ImagePath, tex.GetRawTextureData());
```

Have a look at [this answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/204372/saving-screenshots-to-android-gallery.html)